# Stop a model from selecting the first item when reset

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QAbstractItemModel` for a `QTreeView`. If I reset the model because I am replacing the contents from opening a new file, or if the whole tree is resorted (thus changed) and issuing a `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel`, the first item in the tree is automatically selected because `currentChanged` was emitted with the index of the first entry. Is there a way I can prevent anything from being selected when the model is reset?

Note: this only happens if there already was a selection.

I have tried clearing the selection model before setting the new model in two ways: `selectionModel().clearSelection()` and `selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex(), QItemSelectionModel.Clear)` with not luck. I have also tried setting the focus policy of the tree view to `ClickFocus` so it doesn't automatically select an item if it has focus.

Comment: Sorting does not change the current selection, nor it does even if the `selectionMode` set is "incompatible" with the new sorting. If you clear the model, the selection model should be cleared along with it, so maybe there's something wrong with the clearing implementation of your QAbstractModel. As requested by @eyllanesc, you should share an MRE with us.

Comment: Agreed on the example, but with the abstract model and everything else needed to demonstrate this, it would be huge and take a lot of time to create. I was hoping there was something obvious I was unaware of that causes this. Also, I am sorting manually outside the model then resetting with `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel` and have no clear on the model; when opening a new file, I replace the current model with a new model (and selection model), which is why it is very odd to be happening on open as well.